# can not create instance of my view model class in android

Tags: java, android

MainActivity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //recycle view creation

        adapter=new Adapter_R();
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
        layoutManager=new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        viewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModelM.class);
        viewModel.getGetList_main().observe(this, new Observer<List<Main_Table>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Main_Table> main_tables) {
                adapter.submitList(main_tables);
            }
        });
```

i dont know that where i'm going wrong in log cat its showing that can not initialize ViewModel class i've also tried to use viewmodelprovider insted of viewmodelproviders but still its showing same error
my view model class:

```
public class ViewModelM extends AndroidViewModel {
    Repository_m repository_m;
    public ViewModelM(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        Repository_m repository_m=new Repository_m(application);
        this.repository_m=repository_m;
    }
    //get list
    public LiveData<List<Main_Table>> getGetList_main(){
        return repository_m.getGetList_m();
    }
```

this is my log cat

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yash.note_2_app/com.yash.note_2_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.yash.note_2_app.AndroidRoom.ViewModel.ViewModelM
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3534)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2239)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.yash.note_2_app.AndroidRoom.ViewModel.ViewModelM
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:275)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at com.yash.note_2_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3505)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:100) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2239) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect
```

.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)

Comment: Is that the end of the exception or is there more to it?

Comment: there are few more

Comment: do you want me to share all the exceptions

Comment: The last "Caused by" is the most important one, but yes, the entire things is important.